# Use ERB to access images NOT asset pipeline

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I want to display an dynamically chosen image, thus within the html I call upon the variable `@background_img`, which contains the url to a specific picture. However, doing

```
<body style='background-image: url(<%=@background_img%>);'>
```

simply refuses to display the image for the background. Am I misinterpreting how ERB works, because wouldn't Rails simply precompile the CSS and end up with a working HTML image fetch? Using the Chrome Developer Tools when previewing my app reveals `url()`, and obviously an empty parameter can't fetch the image.

EDIT:
Just wanted to add that I would rather not have to download the images, but keep the urls I already have prepared.

This is the WeatherMan class:

```
require 'rest-client'

class WeatherMan
  #images within accessible data structures, designed to be expandable

  def initialize
@hot = ['https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1515/23959664094_9c59962bb0_b.jpg']
@rain = ['https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7062/6845995798_37c20b1b55_h.jpg']
  end
  def getWeather(cityID)
response = JSON.parse RestClient.get "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=#{cityID}&APPID=bd43836512d5650838d83c93c4412774&units=Imperial"
return {
  temp: response['main']['temp'].to_f.round,
  cloudiness: response['clouds']['all'].to_f.round,
  humidity: response['main']['humidity'].to_f.round,
  windiness: response['wind']['speed'],
  condition_id: response['weather'][0]['id'].to_f,


condition_name: response['weather'][0]['main'],
  condition_description: response['weather'][0]['description'],
  condition_img: response['weather'][0]['icon']
}
  end

  def getImg(temp)
if temp <= 100 #CHANGE!!!
  return @rain[rand(@rain.length)]
elsif  temp <= 32


    return nil
    elsif temp <= 50
      return nil
    elsif  temp <= 75
      return nil
    elsif  temp <= 105
     return nil
       end
      end
    end
```

So sorry about the formatting, on mobile right now.

Now, the controller class:

```
load File.expand_path("../../data_reader.rb", __FILE__)
load File.expand_path("../../weatherstation.rb", __FILE__)
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
   # `sudo python /home/pi/Documents/coding/raspberryPI/weatherStation/app/led_blink.py`
    server = WeatherMan.new
    @outside_data = server.getWeather(4219934)
    @sensor_temp = DRead.read_data(File.expand_path('../../data.txt', __FILE__), 'temperature')
    @sensor_temp = (@sensor_temp.to_f * (9.0/5) + 32).round(2)
    @background_img = server.getImg(@outside_data[:temp])
  end
end
```

Comment: are you sure that the value of your var is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure you can put an ERB tag inside another HTML tag. You can rewrite as `<body style="background-image: url( #{@background_img} );">` and it should work.

Comment: So how are you populating `@background_img`? You mention it's not in the asset pipeline, yet don't give us any information of where it's from

Comment: @RichPeck background_img is populated in the controller, assigned to an array's random index. The array only has String literals pointing towards a URL.

Comment: @taglia I changed it to that, to no avail. The substitution doesn't occur, resulting `background-image: url( #{@background_img} );`

Comment: Can you give me an example of the URL? And can you post your controller code?

Comment: Wow no wonder it's not showing

Comment: My GitHub repo for it: https://github.com/chaseWilliams/raspberryPI

Comment: Let me come back with an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `@background_img` is not populated.

The reason for this *seems* to be your `Weatherman` class. I will attempt to rectify the issue...

---

**Controller**

If you're calling `@background_img` on your *body* tag, it means it's accessible at *every* controller action. Thus, instead of declaring it in a solitary `home` action, you need to make it available each time you load your views:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_background

   private

   def set_background
      server = WeatherMan.new
      @outside_data   = server.getWeather(4219934)
      @sensor_temp    = DRead.read_data(File.expand_path('../../data.txt', __FILE__), 'temperature')
      @sensor_temp    = (@sensor_temp.to_f * (9.0/5) + 32).round(2)
      @background_img = server.getImg(@outside_data[:temp])
   end
end
```

--

**Class**

The main issue I see is that your *class* is not giving you a value. I'll attempt to refactor your class, although I can't promise anything:

```
require 'rest-client'
class WeatherMan

  @@static = {
    hot:  'https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1515/23959664094_9c59962bb0_b.jpg',
    rain: 'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7062/6845995798_37c20b1b55_h.jpg'
  }

  def getWeather(cityID)
     response = JSON.parse RestClient.get weather_url(cityID)  
     return {
        temp:          response['main']['temp'].to_f.round,
        cloudiness:    response['clouds']['all'].to_f.round,
        humidity:      response['main']['humidity'].to_f.round,
        windiness:     response['wind']['speed'],
        condition_id:  response['weather'][0]['id'].to_f,

        condition_name:        response['weather'][0]['main'],
        condition_description: response['weather'][0]['description'],
        condition_img:         response['weather'][0]['icon']
     }
  end

  def getImg(temp)
     #### This should return the image ####
     #### Below is a test              ####
     @@static[:hot]
  end

  private

  def weather_url city
     "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=#{city}&APPID=bd43836512d5650838d83c93c4412774&units=Imperial"
  end
end
```

--

**View**

You *need* to make sure you're getting returned data from your controller in order to populate it in your view.

Because your `getImg` method is returning `nil`, you're getting a `nil` response. I have amended this *for now* with one of the `flickr` links you have included in the class.

If you always have a returned image, the following should work:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<body style='background-image: url(<%= @background_img %>);'>
```

Because your `@background_img` is an external URL, the above should work. If you were using a file from your `asset_pipeline`, you'd want to use [`image_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) etc

Comment: Awesome dude! Finally got code to work. I think the problem was indeed attributed to the WeathMan `getImg` method- it was returning nil, because of a bug in Open Weather Maps that was giving me the temperature in Kelvin (276, etc.), which my code clearly wasn't designed to handle. Thus, it defaulted to nil. Thanks for the help!